# python import pymssql : Library not loaded:libsybdb.5.dylib

Tags: python

I am trying to import pymssql like this:

```
import pymssql
```

And I get this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/apple/.virtualenvs/env376/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymssql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/freetds/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/.virtualenvs/env376/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymssql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: “Reason: image not found” when importing opencv" question answer invalid for me

Answer (score 7):

As it is well explained [here](https://groups.google.com/g/pymssql/c/Tu3Q_-N-1Zc):
In order to get a file from `/usr/local/opt/freetds`, you need

```
brew install freetds
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://gist.github.com/rosiecakes/89d3e77c8dded619ed34dc44d25dd33a) try the below -

`brew install unixodbc`